# subclassing a cell with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possibile to subclassing a cell with a UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.
I need to use this style but I need to move the text and description label to the left.
How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

in your init method for your subclass call super `initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle..`., the detail label will be set up for you and you can access this with the `detailTextLabel` property

set the position of the label(s) in `layoutSubviews`

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand how Can I reassign the position of the labels.. Can you show me an example please?

Comment: override layoutSubviews, call super, then self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 100.0f, 20.0f); substitute in whatever position you want